# Fire-themed enemy ideas

Tags: fauna, fire, classical-elements, video-games

So I'm currently designing a video game lava level and I wanna fill it with fire-based animals that will essentially act as enemies for the players to interact with. So far I've currently got two different animals, fire lizards (which were inspired by Salamanders) and fire birds (which were inspired by Phoenixes). I wanna design at least one more animal so that way my level will have just as my enemy types as the rest of my games levels but I honestly don't know what that final animal should be. I can't use Dragons since I already plan to use them in a different level in the game, and I can't use Demons since I already have a humanoid Ifrit as my game's Fire Elemental. Don't suppose any of you guys and girls could help me out?

Details that I'm looking out for

- Can be based off of something mythological, but only if said mythological figure can be compared to something from the real world (like Salamanders and Phoenixes)
- I don't mind making another quadruped, but I'd personally like to stay away from anything with wings as two winged creatures in one area seems a bit uncreative
- Don't give a damn about realism or why this creature is able to survive and thrive in a lava land (already thought about this already), just looking out for something that's synonymous with the fire element, or likely to be associated with the fire element if an elemental trait never got assigned to it

Comment: What must it be able to do? Also what are the size constraints?

Comment: It must be able to emit fire in some way shape or form (could be from the mouth or from some other place) and for size? Lets say no taller than a 5 foot tall human (go nuts on width and length)

Comment: Currently this question can receive an unending list of ideas. Please make better criteria so it can have a 'best' answer.

Comment: This site is not really intended as a pool in which to fish for ideas. You may want to take the [tour] and visit the [help] in order to become better acquainted with the purpose and expectations of this site. (Besides, I don't really undestand what you would want to do with any story ideas you might receive; user contributions to this site are licensed under the Creative Commons Attribution Share Alike license -- see at the bottom of each and every page. Do you intend to release your game free of charge under a compatible license, and to include credits to respondents?)

Comment: I hear what both of you are saying and I understand. I'm not sure however how to modify my criteria to make identifying a 'best answer' more possible?

Comment: @CrystalKing maybe you can give more direction. I know you're not too interested in realism, but many stories have an inkling of truth or logic behind them. This is what is engaging, as each layer of the story has a surprising depth behind it. Maybe you can ask, assuming a magical fire biome with your creatures in detail, what creature would be best to fill out the roster that makes sense in such a magical fire biome.

Comment: How about a fire mushroom? It can either inflate it's cap like a hot-air balloon, or launch exploding spores. They feed on lava and always start near pools of it. But players are materially organics that allow growth...

Answer (score 3):

How about insectoids?

**Dragonfly's/fireflies.**
For Dragon flies you could go a path of small agile fire breathing flyers that function as glass cannons who deal high damage but are pretty much killed in a single hit.
For fireflies you could have them leave a small trail of fire behind when they fly, so instead of attacking directly let them circle around your player character and closing in and reduced the movability of the player character making them easier targets for the other creatures.

**Hellhounds**
(possibly with multiple heads) like Cerberus  that are fast melee combatants.

**Volcano turtles**
Just like some fantasy stories have turtles that are moving island have volcano turtles that slowly walk across the playing field and launch molten rocks randomly around them with an interval. With a large HP-pool or thick armor combined with their low speed and RNG attack you could make them more like moving obstacles then real enemies seeing they won't be worth the effort to try and kill.

**Arachnids**
spiders with magma/lava webs that burn enemies that walk in to their trap and possibly lava scorpions that release lava from their stinger instead of poison.

**Lava Worms** that can crawl through the lava/magma like the worms can in Dune, being sneak attackers that hide until they are close to an enemy to burst from the lava and strike at their prey.

Comment: Love the idea of the Volcanic Turtle. Wasn't even playing on using them in my forest of water level so they would fit perfectly. Like the other suggestions as well. Also side note, if you had skin thick enough to survive swimming in liquid rock that's as hot as1300 - 2200 degrees, would you be borderline unkillable? Like, I'm sure water and ice would be a noticeable weakness, but could an ordinary sword, axe trident or arrow deal any remote damage whatsoever?

Comment: @CrystalKing honestly i don't know haha. Seeing you said you didn't give a damn about realism i named everything i could think of :D But perhaps make the worms covered in a thick hide that can resist the fire but it has to open to be able to eat/see above the lava making it's face a weak spot.

Comment: So basically like how BotW's Dark Beast Ganon was made up of an indestructible substance and could only sustain damage by ripping open it's skin and shooting the exposed eye? That... actually might just work. Thx so much

Comment: haven't played BotW yet :3 but it's a common game mechanic for invulnerable creatures to expose a weak spot when attacking or making certain movements.

Answer (score 0):

**The Nether!**

[image: nether]

https://evil.fandom.com/wiki/Nether

Minecraft has an entire lava dimension called the Nether.  It is pretty awesome.  All kinds of characteristic monsters live there - floating ghasts that shoot fireballs, skeletal flaming blazes, lava cubes, zombie pigmen etc.

You can lift those for your game!  The concern is copyright and copyright enforcement depends on the owner and infringee.  If you have ghasts in your game Mojang might tell you to quit it.  On the other hand maybe they will think all publicity is good publicity and not mind, or tell you to buy a license for $1.

Seeing creatures you recognize from another game is kind of like realizing you are listening to a cover of a song you know.  Recognizing the familiar in the unfamiliar is a good feeling and the kind of thing there is probably a word for in German.  If you populate your lava level with the denizens of the Nether (or close facsimiles) it will be extra fun for your players who are familiar with Minecraft.